# Is AES encrypted + base64 encoded value still unique?

Tags: cryptography, base64

I encrypt a UTF-8 string + current timestamp using AES 128bit CTR mode with a 4 bytes random initialization vector, which is generated by NodeJS's crypto.randomBytes().

Finally I base64 encode the whole output, using a URL-friendly base64 variant.

Question: the AES output should be unique due to timestamp + random data. But is final base64 string also guaranteed to be unique?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The ciphertext should be unique even without the timestamp due to the unique initialization vector. The IV only has to be unique for CTR mode; a random IV is not necessary, though it shouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Base64 is a reversible transformation, so if input is unique than output will be also unique.